# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-spark

So I've installed Hadoop File System on my machine and I'm using maven dependency to provide my code spark environment. (spark-mllib_2.10)
Now, My code is using spark mllib. And accessing data from Hadoop file system with this code.

```
String finalData = ProjectProperties.hadoopBasePath + ProjectProperties.finalDataPath;
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(jsc.sc(), finalData).toJavaRDD();
```

With following properties set.

```
finalDataPath = /data/finalInput.txt
hadoopBasePath = hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310
```

I am starting the dfs nodes externally through command

```
start-dfs.sh
```

Now, my code works perfectly fine when running from eclipse. But if I export the whole code to an executable jar, it gives me following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
```

I also checked different solutions online given for this issue where people are asking me to add following

```
 hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", 
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()
    );
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.file.impl",
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName()
    );
```

OR

```
<property>
   <name>fs.file.impl</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem</value>
   <description>The FileSystem for file: uris.</description>
</property>

<property>
   <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
   <description>The FileSystem for hdfs: uris.</description>
</property>
```

But I don't use any Hadoop context or hadoop config into my project. Simply load the data from Hadoop using the URL.

Can someone give some answer relevant to this issue?
Please mind that this totally works fine from Eclipse. And only doesn't work if I export the same project as an executable Jar.

**Update**
As suggested in the comment and from the solutions found online, I tried two things.

1. Added dependencies into my pom.xml for `hadoop-core`, `hadoop-hdfs` and `hadoop-client` libraries.
2. Added the above properties configuration to hadoop's site-core.xml as suggested here http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/scm-users/1288xszz7r/no-filesystem-for-scheme-hdfs

But still no luck in getting the error resolved. Gives the same issue locally on my machine as well as one of the remote machines I tried it on.

I also installed hadoop the same way I did on my machine using the link mentioned above.

Comment: Are he hadoop libraries on the classpath when you run your executable jar?  They must be available at runtime.  Eclipse takes care of that for you while developing, but you're on your own with an exported jar.

Comment: Okay. That could be the problem. But I still don't have the whole picture. What are the hadoop libraries that I need on classpath? And how do I add them to classpath? Would it go to any environment variable or something?
Please suggest. I used following with necessary minor changes to install Hadoop on ubuntu machine.
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: So I did add libraries `hadoop-client`, `hadoop-hdfs` and `hadoop-core` into my pom.xml file. And also added the above two configurations to my core-site.xml file according to this guy's suggestion. http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/scm-users/1288xszz7r/no-filesystem-for-scheme-hdfs

But no luck yet.